# Check DWARF version of compilation unit

Tags: debugging, dwarf

all,
is there a tool to check DWARF version of file? Something like this:

```
$ dwarf_tool binary_name
4
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Linux environment? If you have GCC installed, you should have `readelf` executable. So you can try this

`readelf --debug-dump=info binary_name | grep -A 2 'Compilation Unit @'`

Comment: If on Mac OS X, you would use `xcrun dwarfdump -r0 binary_name`.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `llvm-dwarfdump` tool as below

```
llvm-dwarfdump -r 1 binary_name | head | grep Compile
```

Sample output

```
0x00000000: Compile Unit: length = 0x0004710b, format = DWARF32, version = 0x0004, abbr_offset = 0x0000, addr_size = 0x08 (next unit at 0x0004710f)
```